# How to select condition in xslt if the attribute exist in ref url in xml?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have some code is written and XML as per here:

```
<section label="docs">
        <presentation>
          <mini-site title="Documents"/>
          <power-page title="Product Documents"/>
        </presentation>
        <content template="document-gallery">
          <document lanuage="en" ref="http://manuals.frigidaire.com/prodinfo_pdf/Springfield/TIMSEB471MRR1en.pdf" title="Complete Owner's Guide"/>
          <document lanuage="en" ref="http://manuals.frigidaire.com/prodinfo_pdf/Springfield/5995709499.pdf" title="Wiring Diagram"/>
          <document lanuage="en, es, fr" ref="http://manuals.frigidaire.com/prodinfo_pdf/Springfield/TINSEB472MRR0.pdf" title="Installation Instructions"/>
          <document lanuage="en" ref="http://manuals.frigidaire.com/prodinfo_pdf/Specsheets/E30MO65GSS_1213_EN.pdf" title="Product Specifications Sheet"/>
        </content>
      </section>
```

In the URL "ref" it ends with "en.pdf" and lanuage="en".
I want to select those PDF which has lanuage="en" and ref ends with "en.pdf".

Here what i have written:

```
<xsl:template match="document">
    <xsl:if test="select[(@lanuage,'en') and ends-with(@ref,'en.pdf')]">
        <xsl:variable name="href" select="js:call($resource-to-collect,string(@ref))"/>
        <a type="{name()}" href="{$href}"><xsl:apply-templates select="@* except(@ref)"/><xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/></a>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

But it gives me output which has lanuage="en" kindly suggest me on this.

Comment: It will give the exact, as per condition you are searching which @language is 'en'

Comment: could you please let me know how I can satisfy both conditions

Comment: Are you sure your current XSLT outputs anything? The expression `select[(@lanuage,'en') and ends-with(@ref,'en.pdf')]` is looking for a child node called `select`, which doesn't exist in your XML, and so the condition will always be false. In this example, I would expect it to be `<xsl:if test="@language = 'en' and ends-with(@ref, 'en.pdf')">`

Comment: <xsl:if test="@lanuage='en' and ends-with(@ref,'en.pdf')">

Comment: as per my condition it gives me output only of @lanyage,'en' but not with ends-with(@ref,'en.pdf'). i need to satisfy both the conditions, because in some of the case my xml URL: <document ref="http://manuals.frigidaire.com/prodinfo_pdf/Springfield/TIMSEB471MRR1en.pdf" title="Complete Owner's Guide"/> and it doesnt contain lanuage,'en' attribute so that case i need to select "@ref, 'en.pdf'"

Comment: which version of xslt you are using 1.0 or 2.0? 1.0 not support ends-with function.

Comment: <xsl:if test="@lanuage='en' and ends-with(@ref,'en.pdf')">
this code did not worked

Comment: Hi amrendra I am using 2.0

Comment: I have tried this:
<xsl:if test="matches(@lanuage='en' and ends-with(@ref,'en.pdf'))">
but gaves me syntax error

Comment: If if it doesn't contain `lanuage` attribute then you need to use "or" not "and" here. `<xsl:if test="@lanuage='en' or ends-with(@ref,'en.pdf')">`. Or maybe `<xsl:if test="contains(@lanuage, 'en') or ends-with(@ref,'en.pdf')">` if you want to include the one with `lanuage="en, es, fr"`

Comment: you can use this: <xsl:if test="(contains(@ref, $serch)) and (@lanuage = 'en') and (substring-after(@ref, $serch)='')"> and make a variable like <xsl:variable name="serch" select="'en.pdf'"/>

Comment: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7mm

Comment: Note also that XML is case-sensitive: `E30MO65GSS_1213_EN.pdf` does NOT end with `en.pdf`.

Comment: <xsl:if test="(@lanuage = 'en') and (ends-with(lower-case(@ref), 'en.pdf'))"> make lowe-case then use it

Comment: Here is one solution with regex in 2.0: `<xsl:if test="(@lanuage = 'en') and matches(lower-case(@ref), 'en.pdf$')">`

Comment: Hi Tim it worked, Thank you :)

Comment: @Brajesh Narayan Tim C and me code are same are you check both code or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Brijesh try this code:

```
    <xsl:template match="document">
    <xsl:if test="(@lanuage[.]='en') and (ends-with(lower-case(@ref[.]),'en.pdf'))">
        <document>
            <xsl:attribute name="language" select="./@language"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="ref" select="./@ref"/>
        </document>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I think this answer doesn't cover all the comments about lower-case/upper-case and element in sequence

Comment: What about `eN.pdf` or `En.PDF`?